# Swift couldn't infer generic type when I was trying to provide my own implementation of AnySequence

Tags: swift, generics, swift-protocols, type-erasure, associated-types

The problem is when one protocol depends on another through its associated type, compiler isn't able to infer generic types.

So, I was playing around with Swift's type erasure technique trying to become familiar with its idea. Basically it'd been pretty understandable until I got to **Sequence** protocol. It's known that it has an associated type - **Iterator**, which conforms **IteratorProtocol**. That said, I've been trying to achieve similar behavior in my own implementation. That's what I've done:

```swift
final class CustomAnySequence<Element>: Sequence {

    class CustomAnyIterator<Element>: IteratorProtocol {
        private let _next: () -> Element?

        init<I: IteratorProtocol>(_ iterator: I) where I.Element == Element {
            var iterator = iterator
            _next = { iterator.next() }
        }

        func next() -> Element? {
            return _next()
        }
    }

    typealias Iterator = CustomAnyIterator<Element>
    typealias Element = Iterator.Element


    private let _makeIterator: () -> Iterator


    init<S: Sequence>(_ sequence: S) where S.Iterator == Iterator {
        _makeIterator = sequence.makeIterator
    }

    func makeIterator() -> Iterator {
        return _makeIterator()
    }

}

let sequence = CustomAnySequence([1, 2, 3])
```

So, the last line gives the following error: **Generic parameter 'Element' could not be inferred**.

Then if I try to fix it by explicitly specifying Element type:

```swift
let sequence = CustomAnySequence<Int>([1, 2, 3])
```

it's not making it better. The next Xcode complaint is: **Generic parameter 'S' could not be inferred**.

**So is there my fault, or it's just too much overhead for Swift's type inference?**

Actually, I've run into another possible implementation - it's using private subclass wrapping. I don't really like it (that's why I was trying to do it on my own) because there are "fatal-error-must-be-subclassed" methods in superclass's implementations, which don't contribute to clean code. Also, I'm not sure how I could implement this functionality by the initializer of CustomAnySequence (I've only found it possible by making a static method). Despite all that, that's the code:

```swift
class CustomAnySequence<Element>: Sequence {
    class Iterator: IteratorProtocol {
        func next() -> Element? {
            fatalError("Must be overriden")
        }
    }

    func makeIterator() -> Iterator {
        fatalError("Must be overriden")
    }
}

private final class CustomAnySequenceImplementation<S: Sequence>: CustomAnySequence<S.Element> {
    final class IteratorImplementation: Iterator {
        var wrapped: S.Iterator

        init(_ wrapped: S.Iterator) {
            self.wrapped = wrapped
        }

        override func next() -> S.Element? {
            return wrapped.next()
        }
    }

    var sequence: S

    init(_ sequence: S) {
        self.sequence = sequence
    }

    override func makeIterator() -> IteratorImplementation {
        return IteratorImplementation(sequence.makeIterator())
    }
}


extension CustomAnySequence {
    static func make<S: Sequence>(_ sequence: S) -> CustomAnySequence<Element> where S.Element == Element {
        return CustomAnySequenceImplementation<S>(sequence)
    }
}

func printInts(_ sequence: CustomAnySequence<Int>) {
    for element in sequence {
        print(element)
    }
}


printInts(CustomAnySequence.make([1, 2, 3]))
printInts(CustomAnySequence.make(Set([4, 5, 6])))
```

It actually **does** work, but it looks a bit like a boilerplate. **At least, if you realize how to improve it by using an initializer, please let me know. Thank you in advance!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with the first implementation is that

```
let sequence = CustomAnySequence([1, 2, 3])
```

does not satisfy the constraint in

```
init<S: Sequence>(_ sequence: S) where S.Iterator == Iterator
```

`[1, 2, 3]` is a sequence, but its iterator type is not your `CustomAnyIterator`. What you really want is to pass a sequence with the same *element* type, not the same iterator type:

```
init<S: Sequence>(_ sequence: S) where S.Element == Element
```

and pass `sequence.makeIterator()` to the init method of `CustomAnyIterator`.

Note also the inner class can inherit the `Element` type placeholder from the outer class, and that the type aliases are not really needed.

```
final class CustomAnySequence<Element>: Sequence {

    class CustomAnyIterator: IteratorProtocol {
        private let _next: () -> Element?

        init<I: IteratorProtocol>(_ iterator: I) where I.Element == Element {
            var iterator = iterator
            _next = { iterator.next() }
        }

        func next() -> Element? {
            return _next()
        }
    }

    private let _makeIterator: () -> CustomAnyIterator

    init<S: Sequence>(_ sequence: S) where S.Element == Element {
        _makeIterator = { CustomAnyIterator(sequence.makeIterator()) }
    }

    func makeIterator() -> CustomAnyIterator {
        return _makeIterator()
    }
}
```

You may also consider to use a `struct` instead of a `class`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Spend a lot of time resolving this issue

Comment: @Yury: You are welcome. – I have added another simplification.